# prove that the norms $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_2$ are equivalent.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

let $X$ be a Banach space with respect to each of the norms $\|.\|_1$ and  $\|.\|_2$. Suppose a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converge to $y$ in $(X,\|.\|_1)$ and to $z$ in $(X,\|.\|_2)$  such that $y=z.$

prove that the norms $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_2$  are equivalent.

let $T: (X,\|.\|_1)\to (X,\|.\|_2) $ be identity map.

i want to show $T$ is continuous, then  by open mapping theorem, we will be done.

but can i show $T$ is continuous. i am give a particular sequence $(x_n)$ which converge to same point $y$ in both spaces.how can i use this ?

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: What you need is that every sequence that converges in $\|\cdot\|_1$ also converges in $\|\cdot\|_2$ and to the same element. The existence of one such series is not enough, as for any $x\in X$ you can just look at $\frac xn$, which will converge to zero wrt any norm on $X$.

Comment: How about Closed Graph Theorem?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam how do we use that in this case

Comment: Suppose that $x_n \to 0$ in $(X,\|.\|_1)$ and $x_n=T(x_n) \to y$ in $(X,\|.\|_2)$, then by assumption $y=0$